# Run xcode project with distribution profile on it

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, profiles

I have created an iOS application, and wanted to submit it to the App Store. 
I saw a tutorial on how to do that, and understood that I need to create a Distribution profile and replace it with the Development profile. So I did that but before sending it to the App Store. I want to check it last with that profile on it (the distribution profile).
Can I run Xcode project when I add a distribution profile?
because when I tried running it on a real device, an error popped up: "the provisioning profile "XXXXX" was not found".
So i went to the Devices tab and tried adding the file of the provisioning profile, and it didn't allow me to.

What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use distribution profile to run the app on your device directly from your device.

Now Apple provides beta testing of apps using **iTunes Connect**. So you can opt for that option as an alternative.

Refer [**Beta Testing Your iOS App**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html) for more details

Comment: So why I cant add any distribution profile to xcode?

Comment: @NirGofman: Did you created the distribution profile ? If yes, download it and double click to add it to the profiles library, change your bundle id and choose the profile in build settings tab

Comment: The problem is that the profile exist in the profiles list but when I trying to run the app on real device, an error: the provisioning profile "NAME" was not found.

Comment: @NirGofman You can't run the app to real device using distribution profile

Comment: why? - you said "You can use distribution profile to run the app on your device directly from your device."

Comment: So you trying to say that I CANT run the app with dis' profile? - its so idiot...

Comment: @NirGofman : You can use beta testing option, through which you can verify the app working on distribution profile

Comment: @MidhunMP but that's quite a round-about way to test whether your app works, right?!  Having to deploy to TestFlight then download it again :/

Perhaps the question is, how different is your TestFlight build from the development build?  There's a potential for them to be very different, but also very similar.

Comment: The larger issue is: can I really not debug my code using a dist profile on a real device? Things like push notifications or camera issues must be debugged on a device (with debug and prod builds potentially utilizing different operations server side).

Comment: @BenJammin You can put production build for internal testing via testflight and test the push and camera features. There is no way to "debug" production build.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do by applying small tweak.

- Open you **Xcode** project
- click on your **target**.
- choose **edit scheme** from list.
- choose **Run** tab from left.
- select **info** tab from top.
- select **Build Configuration** and choose **release** from drop-down list.

Now delete your existing app, from device if exist.
And run the app from Xcode.

After completion of compiling for app, it would show some error dialog and will stop execution, **ignore it**.

Now app is installed on your device with distribution profile.
Re-run the app.

Cheers!

Comment: This is partially true, from my (limited) experience. This does seem to set the app to use its 'production' configuration, but it seems like the provisioning profile in use may still be a 'development' profile. In my testing, the APNs token I got was still the 'sandbox' token, not a 'production' token. Unfortunately this solution didn't quite work for me.